# How can I apply the same keywords to multiple photos in Lightroom Mobile?

Tags: lightroom, iphone, keywords, mobile

I’m using Lightroom CC for mobile on an iPhone SE. Is there a way to apply one or more keywords to a *group* of photos, or do I have to retype them for each photo? This is easy in the desktop version, but the mobile version has me stumped!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, there’s currently not a way (in version 3.1.0 for iPhone) to select a group of photos and then apply the same keyword(s) to your selection.

However, there is a feature to copy one photo’s keyword(s), and then paste these to other photos in your album, one at a time.

1. Go a photo where you’d like to start. Go to the Keywords view, if you’re not there already. Add your desired keyword(s) to the photo. The following screenshot shows several added keywords that I want to apply to a second image.

[image: step 1]

2. Tap the three dots / ellipsis in the upper right corner to display a menu. Choose “Copy Keywords.”

[image: step 2]

3. Swipe or go the the image where you want to apply the keywords. Display the menu again, and tap “Paste Keywords.”

[image: step 3]

4. You should now see the pasted keywords. If you want to apply the keywords to additional images, return to Step 3.

[image: step 4]